# CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR: b'error while writing to output stream' on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, svg, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the [cairosvg](http://cairosvg.org) library in order to convert some svg files into png using google cloud functions, however I got the error `CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR` when I run inside a google cloud function.

```
svg_string = """
<svg baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
"""
cairosvg.svg2png(
    bytestring=svg_string, write_to='/tmp/output.png')
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 281, in run_background_function
_function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 171, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event)
File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions_v1beta2/worker.py", line 168, in call_user_function
event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 54, in handle_upload bytestring=svg_string,
write_to='/tmp/output.png') File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairosvg/__init__.py", line 45,
in <lambda> surface_type.convert(*args, **kwargs))(_surface_type) File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairosvg/surface.py", line 139, in convert instance.finish() File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairosvg/surface.py", line 463, in finish self.cairo.write_to_png(self.output) File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairocffi/surfaces.py", line 653, in write_to_png self._pointer, _encode_filename(target))) File
"/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 79, in _check_status raise exception(message, status) OSError: [Errno
cairo returned CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR: b'error while writing to output stream'] 11
```

Comment: Does the error persist if you add a `viewBox` to the `svg` element?

Comment: @Dustin works flawless, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cairosvg` package can't render a SVG with relative heights or widths without a `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element.

Comment: Can you clarify the solution?

Comment: You must add a `viewBox` attribute to the `svg` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox